# Why does the NUnit Test Adapter give me FileNotFound Exception while converting features?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nunit, specflow

I'm using VisualStudio 2015. I have installed the NUnit3 (3.5), NUnit3TestAdapter (3.6 also installed the VS extention), SpecFlow (2.1.0) and corresponding Selenium drivers NuGet packages.

I have one solution with two projects in them. One projects builds perfectly and discovers the feature test in them. But my other project build perfectly and the test aren't discovered. If I go to the test output I get the following FileNotFound / Converting error:

```
------ Discover test started ------
NUnit Adapter 3.6.1.0: Test discovery starting
Exception System.IO.FileNotFoundException, Exception converting Calculations.Calculations.Feature.SendANewQuote.SendANewQuote("18-1980","150","Yearly","1337","RiskProfile","email@email.com",System.String[])
Could not find file 'PathToCalculations\bin\Config\Calculations.pdb'.
```

It is the same for all my other tests in that project. I don't have that problem with my other project but all the references and packages are the same.

How can I fix this error so that the NUnit Test Adapter can do it's magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was recently a change with either the adapter, or VS, that means a pdb file must be generated when using the adapter. There is an open issue to investigate this here: https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/276

It sounds like you might not be generating a pdb for the 'Calculations' project. You can turn it on by going in to the project settings > Build > Advanced, and selecting `full` or `pdb-only` from the Debug Info dropdown.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my problem!